# GCP: how do I restore a cloud sql instance from the latest backup using cloud functions?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-sql

I have two cloud sql instances in GCP: `production` and `staging`. My production instance is set to have a daily backup. Periodically, I restore the latest `production` backup to my `staging` instance. Right now, I am doing that manually. I'd like to set up a cloud function triggered by a cloud scheduler (let's say 3x a week; I have no issue configuring this) which does exactly that: restores my `staging` cloud sql from the latest `production` backup.

The issue is that I'm not familiar with serverless functions or the gcloud API. I did happen to find these related rescources:

- https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/admin-api/rest/v1/instances/restoreBackup
- https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/backup-recovery/restoring#restorebackups-another-instance

I'm still stuck though.

Comment: What are you asking for? Someone to write code for you? You have several items to learn. 1) How to write a Cloud Function; 2) How to deploy a Cloud Function; 3) How to secure a Cloud Function; 4) How to schedule a Cloud Function. There are numerous tutorials on the Internet to learn those basics. A shortcut I use to learn a specific Google Cloud REST API is to use the CLI `gcloud`. Add the `--log-http` command flag to see the exact REST API payload. Duplicating that in any language is very easy with those details.

Comment: @JohnHanley I know how to do 1-4. I've written cloud functions before. I've just had difficulty with this specific GCP REST API :/ . But thanks for the tip, I'll definitely be trying that out using the CLI

Comment: I commented on areas to learn because you said `I'm not familiar with serverless functions`. There is so much documentation, tutorials, labs, etc about functions that I was trying to point you to the key areas to learn first.